# Why don't if statments work when repeated in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a grid where the different boxes will blink based off of a binary value defined within my HTML document. I have created a grid in HTML, where the background colour is automatically green and what I'm trying to achieve is that if my value changes to from 0 to 1 for each of the grid items it will then change the colour to red and blink respectively.

I have managed to get the first one working and thought I could just repeat the code with different variables assigned, however this hasn't worked. The weird thing is, if I remove the code for the first box the second box will start working.

Do I need to add some extra code in JS to separate the if statments?

CSS'

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item" id = "blink1">A</div>
  <div class="grid-item" id = "blink2">B</div>
 
</div>


<div class = "values">  
<div id = "$box1value"> 1 </div>
<div id = "$box2value"> 1 </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var $box1 = document.getElementById("$box1value").innerHTML;

if ($box1 > 0) {
    document.getElementById("blink1").style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
    // blink "on" state
    function show() {
        if (document.getElementById)
            document.getElementById("blink1").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    // blink "off" state
    function hide() {
        if (document.getElementById)
            document.getElementById("blink1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    for (var i = 900; i < 99999999999; i = i + 900) {
        setTimeout("hide()", i);
        setTimeout("show()", i + 450);
    }

} else {
    document.getElementById("blink1").style.backgroundColor = '#098700';
}




/////////////////////next box/////////////////////////////

var $box2 = document.getElementById("$box2value").innerHTML;

if ($box2 > 0) {
    document.getElementById("blink2").style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';// blink "on" state
    function show() {
        if (document.getElementById)
            document.getElementById("blink2").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    // blink "off" state
    function hide() {
        if (document.getElementById)
            document.getElementById("blink2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    for (var i = 900; i < 99999999999999999; i = i + 900) {
        setTimeout("hide()", i);
        setTimeout("show()", i + 450);
    }

} else {
    document.getElementById("blink2").style.backgroundColor = '#098700';
}
```

Comment: if-statements should not contain function declarations. If you want to conditionally create a function, assign a function expression to a variable: `var show = function () { ... }`. Also, you should be passing the functions themselves to `setTimeout`, not strings. I suspect the use of strings rather than actual functions is the primary cause of your issue.

Comment: how to shoot at your feet in sixty seconds!

Comment: Thanks JLRishe, please could you elaborate on passing the functions themselves to setTimeout. Where are the strings Ive used instead of this? Apologies if it’s a stupid question...still learning.

Comment: Working on a couple of different solutions. I'll post my answer shortly. Testing them now.

Answer (score 2):

## 2 different solutions (all JS vs. mostly CSS)

1. Keeping the core functionality in JS
2. Leveraging CSS for core functionality

> I see what you're trying to achieve here, and I see a couple of different ways to accomplish this. Both of the solutions below allow your code to dynamically loop through any number of box items— no need to write a separate block for each item.
>
> The first example below is modeled more similar to yours, based on
> your code but rewritten to work more dynamically. The second solution
> further down greatly simplifies things by moving all initialization
> scripting into CSS, leaving JS responsible for only boolean switching
> if you need to make any real-time state switches.

---

## #1. Keeping the core functionality in JS

This solution modifies your original code to dynamically read the values for however many values there are, and then looping through them. In order to perform the repeated blinking in JS, I would suggest using setInterval. You'll also need to move that outside the rest of the code when using a loop or you'll end up with a conflict between the loop's iterator and the setInterval's and setTimeout's timing. More on that [here](https://medium.com/@axionoso/watch-out-when-using-settimeout-in-for-loop-js-75a047e27a5f). You can see the working example below:

```js
function blink(el) {
    if (el.style) {
        setInterval(function() {
            el.style.visibility = "visible";
            setTimeout(function() {
                el.style.visibility = "hidden";
            }, 450);
        }, 900);
    }
}

const $boxes = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="blink"]');
for (const $box of $boxes) {
    var boxId = $box.id.match(/\d+/)[0]; // store the ID #
    if (document.getElementById('$box' + boxId + 'value')) {
        var boxValue = parseInt(document.getElementById('$box' + boxId + 'value').innerHTML);
        if (boxValue) {
            $box.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
            blink($box);
        } else {
            $box.style.backgroundColor = '#098700';
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 50px;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
    background-color: #098700;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.values {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item" id="blink1">A</div>
    <div class="grid-item" id="blink2">B</div>
    <div class="grid-item" id="blink3">C</div>
</div>
<div class="values">  
    <div id="$box1value">1</div>
    <div id="$box2value">0</div>
    <div id="$box3value">1</div>
</div>
```

**CodePen:** https://codepen.io/brandonmcconnell/pen/ecc954bad5552962574c080631700932

---

## #2. Leveraging CSS for core functionality

This solution moves all of your JS code (color and animation) to the CSS, moving the binary boolean switch 0/1 to data-attributes on the grid-items themselves instead of separate items and then trigger any boolean switches on those containers using JS by targeting them by another attribute such as ID, or as I used in my example below, another data-attribute I called `data-blink-id`. This is my recommended solution if you're able to move all of this logic into CSS. It'll be much easier to maintain and to manipulate in real-time, as all it requires to change state is a simple boolean switch.

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 50px;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
    background-color: #098700;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.grid-item[data-blink-status="1"] {
    background-color: #f00;
    animation: blink 900ms linear infinite forwards;
}
@keyframes blink {
    0%, 50% { opacity: 1; }
    51%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item" data-blink-id="1" data-blink-status="1">A</div>
    <div class="grid-item" data-blink-id="2" data-blink-status="0">B</div>
    <div class="grid-item" data-blink-id="3" data-blink-status="1">C</div>
</div>
```

**CodePen:** https://codepen.io/brandonmcconnell/pen/5b4f3090b3590902b11d50af43361758

To trigger the binary boolean switch on an item (turn ON/OFF), use the below JS command. I've commented this out in the CodePen example linked above. Un-comment this JS line to activate it and switch ON the block with `data-blink-id=2`

```js
document.querySelector('[data-blink-id="2"]').setAttribute('data-blink-status', 1);
```

Comment: For the 2nd example, in addition to that one-liner to flip the boolean switch on/off. You could write up a fairly concise function for quick use in your code. Ex: `function blinkSwitch(id, status) { if (document.querySelector('[data-blink-id="'+ id + '"]')) document.querySelector('[data-blink-id="'+ id + '"]').setAttribute('data-blink-status', status); }` and then invoke the function like this: `blinkSwitch(3,0)` to turn the box of ID **3** off (`0`).

Answer (score 0):

Even though your functions are declared inside `if` statements, they are still global.

So, you essentially redeclare the `show` and `hide` functions, and they stop working.

To make those functions local to the `if` statement, you'll have to use one of the ES6 block scope declarations, `let` or `const`, like this:

```
const show = function(){ ... }
const hide = function(){ ... }
```

To do this, you should also replace `setTimeout`'s first argument with a reference to the function (actually, you should always do that):

```
setTimeout(hide, i)
setTimeout(show, i + 450)
```

Other improvements you can make:

- Avoid that loop that sets timeouts. It's ugly, takes long to execute, and doesn't work forever. Instead, replace `setTimeout`s with `setInterval`s.
- Remove the `if (document.getElementById)` part. You can count on it to be defined (it has been around for a *loooong* time...)

So, you get to:

```
var $box1 = document.getElementById("$box1value").innerHTML;

if ($box1 > 0) {
    document.getElementById("blink1").style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';// blink "on" state
    const show = function () {
        document.getElementById("blink1").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    // blink "off" state
    const hide = function () {
        document.getElementById("blink1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    let flag = false //This is needed to keep track if the element is visible

    setInterval(function(){
      if(flag = !flag)
        hide()
      else
        show()
    }, 450);

} else {
    document.getElementById("blink1").style.backgroundColor = '#098700';
}

/////////////////////next box/////////////////////////////

var $box2 = document.getElementById("$box2value").innerHTML;

if ($box2 > 0) {
    document.getElementById("blink2").style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';// blink "on" state
    const show = function () {
        document.getElementById("blink2").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    // blink "off" state
    const hide = function () {
        document.getElementById("blink2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    let flag = false //This is needed to keep track if the element is visible

    setInterval(function(){
      if(flag = !flag)
        hide()
      else
        show()
    }, 450);

} else {
    document.getElementById("blink2").style.backgroundColor = '#098700';
}
```